# What is the need for hell when we also have to suffer the reactions of karma

Tags: karma

It is my understanding that we all have to either enjoy or suffer for our actions good or bad- in millions of life times if we continue to be in ignorance. That being the case, what is the need to punish people in hell again? I guess the same can be said of heaven also. Why do we have to enjoy in heaven and then also enjoy the results of good deeds on earth?